# where is "PS_META_DESCRIPTION" and "PS_META_KEYWORDS" and how can i change it?

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

in classes/Meta.php i found this lines in "completeMetaTags" function:

```
if (empty($meta_tags['meta_description'])) {
      $meta_tags['meta_description'] = Configuration::get('PS_META_DESCRIPTION', $context->language->id) ? Configuration::get('PS_META_DESCRIPTION', $context->language->id) : '';
}
if (empty($meta_tags['meta_keywords'])) {
      $meta_tags['meta_keywords'] = Configuration::get('PS_META_KEYWORDS', $context->language->id) ? Configuration::get('PS_META_KEYWORDS', $context->language->id) : '';
}
```

it seems, when a page doesn't have any keywords or description, it tries to set "PS_META_KEYWORDS" and "PS_META_DESCRIPTION" to those.

but the value of "PS_META_DESCRIPTION" and "PS_META_KEYWORDS" are empty for me and i don't know where can i change these values ?

i searched "configuration" table but i can't find "PS_META_DESCRIPTION" and "PS_META_KEYWORDS" values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot find what you are searching for in the whole raw Prestashop 1.6 repository, except the legacy code you are talking about.

A way to set this could be to make a simple module with these fields to custom, you can find an helper here : https://validator.prestashop.com

Anyway it's not possible with the actual version, it surely was in the past.